# Best way to prevent users from filling up all free btrfs disk space?

Tags: partition, disk-usage, btrfs

Many years ago I had an application that went out-of-control and filled up all disk space. This caused write failures in system processes that maintain some kind of database (in the wider sense), resulting in those databases becoming corrupt. I would like to avoid that.

Using ext2/3/4, some percentage of disk space can be reserved for the super-user using the `-m` option of `mke2fs` exactly for this purpose ("allows root-owned daemons, such as syslogd(8), to continue to  function  correctly after non-privileged processes are prevented from writing to the filesystem").

However, I prefer btrfs over ext2/3/4 for its snapshot features and btrfs does not have such an option. It has disk quotas instead, but those tend to cause performance problems with snapshots and I also found them to be unreliable.

Another idea is to have separate partitions for user-writable spaces, however having seperate partitions for `/home`, `/tmp` and `/var/tmp` (are there any more user-writable locations?) feels like an overkill and each of them has to have some safety margin over the predicted usage separately, wasting disk space.

Are there any other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea to use separate partitions is the only practical one right now.  However, it really isn't overkill.  People have been using separate partitions for this purpose for *decades* because it works.  Some general advice:

- `/home` being on a separate partition is standard configuration for many distributions when not using BTRFS, so there's good support for it in all major software already.  THis is the big one to worry about, as it's where 95% of users will place 95% of their files.
- `/tmp` should actually ideally not be a partition.  You almost certainly want it to instead be a `tmpfs` mount with it's own size limit.  This will usually improve performance and avoid wasting disk space, as almost nothing bigger than a few KB gets put in `/tmp` most of the time.
- `/var/tmp` may also be better off being a `tmpfs` mount, especially if you have *lots* of RAM and a decent amount of swap space.
- Beyond those, depending on your exact system configuration, it may be possible for users to write arbitrary amounts of data (directly or indirectly) to `/var/lib`, `/var/cache`, `/var/games` (if there's no `/var/lib/games`), `/var/mail`, `/var/spool`, and possibly any storage directories used for network services (`/var/www` or `/var/ftp` for example).  Personally, I would just put `/var/cache`, `/var/spool`, and `/var/lib` on their own partition, and when that starts to get full just nuke stuff in sub-directories of `/var/cache`.  `/var/mail` should almost always be it's own partition if you actually use it, though BTRFS is probably not the best choice for that.
- There may be other places too.  The official [FHS](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs-3.0.html) may be of some interest, as it lists the standard layout used by almost all Linux distributions, and mentions what goes where.